# What are my options for wiring to a 2nd baseboard heater?

Tags: wiring

I have a 20amp double pole breaker in my panel. I am running 12/2 to my double pole thermostat. From the thermostat I have 12/2 running to the left side of the baseboard heater (Marley manufacturing / Berko 2548). Now when I connect the second heater about 20” or so away is it preferable to run

1. a second wire back to the thermostat or
2. run a wire from the second heater back to the left side of the first heater and connect it there or
3. can I just run a wire from the second heater to the Right side connection box of the first heater

#3 would be the easiest way but don’t know if it has to be directly connected to the left side where wire from thermostat is connected.

Comment: Do your heaters actually have connections at both ends, or is the box at one end empty? To put it another way, what's the brand and model number so we can look at the specifications? Some might have pass-through wiring to ease end-to end connections, some don't (all the ones I recall running into seemed to only have wires for connection to at one end. That does not mean all are made the same way.) On the third hand, for the sake of your power bill, get a cold-climate mini-split heat pump and drop your heating cost a huge amount .vs. baseboard electric heat.

Comment: Hi. There is a box at both ends. I haven’t looked inside but both ends have the same structure-a metal plate with a screw at the bottom

Comment: You need to look at the heater instructions and see what they say about pass-through wiring.  It's probably possible but may require high-temp wire.  The instructions will say for sure.  I completely agree that you'll go broke running this heater unless you really know what you're doing with electric tariffs.  If you don't care because the tenant will pay, you're not allowed to DIY work in rental units.

Comment: It is a Marley manufacturing. / Berko 2548. Got these really cheap just for some occasional heating. Not worth it to get anything else. Thanks

Comment: Not a rental unit. So if I run a wire from the second heater to where the connection is in the left one all will be good

Comment: Always best to put important details like make/model # into the original post. Comments aren't always read and can get deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Read [the instructions.](https://www.marleymep.com/system/files/node/file/field-file//5200-2194-010_3.pdf)

You can wire two adjacent heaters "Left and right" and they can be supplied from either end, but apparently only the "commercial" models (evidently that would be C2548 rather than 2548) have a wireway to carry cables from end to end inside the heater.

So, rather than wire to the left end of the heater on the left, wire to the right end of the heater on the left and the left end of the heater on the right, as shown in "connection for adjacent heaters" (image is from the linked instructions. Do go read them in their entirety.)

If you have already committed to the left end of the left heater, option 3 is out, so option 2 or 1.

[image: Figure 5 from the PDF instructons linked above.]

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I will go with option 2. Weekend project.

Answer (score 0):

You run the wires with the shortest or easiest run. The wiring is run inside the wall and comes out at the heater j box where a splice can be made and the wiring goes back in the wall to # 2. If it would be shorter from the thermostat that would be fine. Both heaters are in parallel so it really is doing it with a short run , ok some may say different but that’s how they are wired in the Pacific Northwest where many homes had base boards or ceiling cable heat. High end had forced air electric because power was super cheap thanks to the Bonneville hydroelectric dam. I have wired dozens of homes usually in 10awg and copper costs so the shortest run is how most are wired.

Comment: I am looking at the two heaters. The left one left side has 2 black wires twisted together and the right side of this heater has a red and black(that are ooose-heaters bought used). Now the left side of the right heater has 2 loose black wires and the right side of that heater has a red and black twisted together. Was this wired correctly by previous owner. And what is the best way for me to wire it 240v. Thanks

Comment: Are the heaters 240v? Wire colors can mean several things or nothing at all what model are the heaters (voltage and wattage is helpful)

Comment: I actually scanned the comments and noticed Berko/2548. The wattage is 2548/240V=10.61 amps sorry you cannot put 2 on 1 circuit you are limited by code to 16 amps on a 20 amp circuit. This is why most are wired with 10 awg then 2 would be ok on a 30 amp circuit if listed most were. You would need to pull a second circuit for the second heater.

Comment: They are 240v. Marley manufacturing/Berko. One is 1500w(left one) and the right one is 2000w

Comment: On the heater, when I add up the total amps it comes out to 14.6 according to the stickers on the units

Comment: The web site shows the berko/2548 the wattage is 2548. This is why the values were asked for, are you sure both are 240v

Comment: I just checked one is 8.4 @240v and the other is 6.3@240v

Comment: I actually have pictures of the two on my phone. But don’t know how to get them to you. I don’t think I can attach a picture. I could email??